# Reading multiple files from directory in R

Tags: r

I have a series of csv files in a directory.

I have tried:

```
fileslist <- list.files(path="/Users/joker/csv_test/", pattern=".csv")
sapply(fileslist, read.csv)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '11NORTHBOUND.csv': No such file or directory
```

As you can see, it is correctly reading a filename (11NORTHBOUND.csv). What are the possible reasons for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the files is incorrect in your sapply line, because you the path was not included in your vector of file names.  files.list() has an option full.names, which defaults to FALSE.  If you use full.names=TRUE (so that "the directory path is prepended to the file names, to give a relative file path"), the code will work.

```
fileslist <- list.files(path="/Users/joker/csv_test/", pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE)
sapply(fileslist, read.csv)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not in the same directory as your files. Verify using `getwd()`. The following will probably work:

```
fileslist <- list.files(path="/Users/joker/csv_test/", pattern=".csv")
MyFileList <- lapply(fileslist, function(i) read.csv(paste0("/Users/joker/csv_test/", i))
```

To test beforehand, use

```
testFile <- read.csv(paste0("/Users/joker/csv_test/", fileslist[1]))
```